# Bound on sum of $x$ independent uniform random variables.

Tags: probability

Let $D_i \sim U[0,\ldots n-1]$, and $D=\sum_{i=1}^{x}D_i$. So, 
$$E[D]\approx \frac{nx}{2}.$$

I want to show that $\Pr(D\le\frac{nx}{4})$ is exponentially small.

Are there some known bounds that I can use here? Thanks!

Comment: If we take $x=1$ then $Pr(D \leq \frac{n}{4}) \approx \frac{1}{4}$, no? Is there some condition on $x$?

Comment: I tried with the Chernoff bound. It looks like it works (the probability will be exponentially small in $x$), but it works only for the parameter $t=1/n$. Is it OK to make $t$ non-constant?

Comment: Let's say it should be exponential in $x$. In my case $\log n <x<\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure how Chernoff would help you here since $D_{i}$ are not binary or in ${-1,1}$.

Comment: You can use Chernoff in any case I think, you just have to calculate the MGF, and select an appropriate $t>0$. In this case it worked but for $t=1/n$. I'm not sure it can be non-constant...

Comment: $$E[e^{-t D}]=\Pi_{i=1}^{x}E[e^{-t D_i}]=\left(\frac{e^{-nt}-1}{n(e^{-t}-1)}\right)^{x}$$
Now we can use a Chernoff bound:
$$\Pr(D\le a)\le\frac{E[e^{-tD}]}{e^{-ta}})$$
By taking $a=\frac{nx}{4}$, we get:
$$\Pr(D\le\frac{nx}{4})\le \left(\frac{e^{-nt}-1}{n(e^{-t}-1)e^{-tn/4}}\right)^{x}$$

If I chose now $t=1/n$, the expression in the parentheses is less than 1, and thus for large values of $x$ I get desirable probability.

Comment: @Michael +1, but you should post that as an answer.

Comment: But I'm not sure that it is correct... What do you think?

Comment: *If I chose now t=1/n, the expression in the parentheses is less than 1*... Well, only if $n\geqslant3$ (and, even then, I fail to see why this should be obvious).

Comment: Yes, this is true only for $n\ge 3$. If you take $t=1/n$, you get constant in enumerator, and the the denominator becomes $n(e^{-1/n}-1)$ which is monotone (its derivative has a constant sign). Also the limit of the whole expression is slightly above 0.8 when $n\rightarrow \infty$. 
@Did, is there some other (better) approach to bound the some of uniform random variables?

Comment: @Michael Does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality give you what you want?

Comment: @Majid, unfortunately it won't work... It will give a probability of $\approx e^{-x^2/n}$, so if $x\approx \sqrt{n}$ this will give only a constant probability. My proof above (it it is correct) gives exponential (in $x$) probability.

Comment: @Michael In that case I am a little concerned your proof could be wrong as I would be surprised if the Hoeffding bound is that loose.  I could be wrong of course...

Comment: @Majid, I think that the problem with Hoeffding is that it is too general (it works for any distribution). In my proof I taylored the value of $t$ so that it worked. Almost any other value of $t$ won't get the desired result. Of course I may be wrong, so if anybody can verify my proof I would be very grateful.

Comment: @Michael Until someone does directly, you can of course approximate the sum of a large number of uniform random variables very accurately by a normal distribution using the central limit theorem. You know the tail bounds of a normal distribution precisely.

Comment: That's right,  Once I have the normal distribution, I have the exponential tail, but how exactly I can quantify the approximation to the normal distribution?

Comment: @Michael http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem I believe.  But in the first instance, as a sanity check, assume it is exact and see if you get the same tail bound. If you don't you can be pretty sure you have made a mistake.

Comment: @Majid, using the CLT:
$\Pr(D\le nx/4)=\Pr(\sqrt{x}(\tfrac{1}{x}\sum D_i-n/2))\le -\sqrt{x}n/4)=\Phi_{N(0,\sigma^2)}(-\sqrt{x}n/4)$. Where $\sigma^2=n^2/12$. This $F_{N(0,\sigma^2)}(-\sqrt{x}n/4)$ gives much smaller exponential probability than $0.9^x$. So, it looks that it works. What do you say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use Chernoff bound: 
\begin{align}
\Pr \left(D \le \frac{nx}{4}\right) &\le \frac{E[e^{-tD}]}{e^{-t\left(nx/4\right)}}\\
E[e^{-tD}] =\Pi_{i=1}^{x}E[e^{-tD_i}]&=\left(\frac{1-e^{-tn}}{n(1-e^{-t})}\right)^{x}\\
\Pr \left(D \le \frac{nx}{4}\right) &\le \left(\frac{1-e^{-tn}}{n(1-e^{-t})e^{-tn/4}}\right)^{x}
\end{align}
By taking $t=1/n$ we obtain for $n\ge 5$:
\begin{align}
\frac{1-e^{-tn}}{n(1-e^{-t})e^{-tn/4}} < 0.9,
\end{align}
and thus:
\begin{align}
\Pr \left(D \le \frac{nx}{4}\right) &\le 0.9^{x}
\end{align}